# Keyboard covering the Input field in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I am working in ionic4, I have a login page with Username and password input field. After building with ionic cordova , in Android device landscape view when I select any of the input field, the Keyboard is popup above the view and not focused the selected field. How can I gain focus and auto scroll the view up when the Keyboard is popup when selecting the Input field.

Comment: By default app setting that should be done , but did you install keyboard plugin?

Comment: alreay added
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.3" />

Comment: I think the current keyboard version is more than 2.1.3 , upgrade the keyboard plugin since there are some bugs in keyboard versions.

Comment: I tried latest <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.2.0" /> also. But it has same issue

Comment: Go to platforms/android/app/src/androidManifest.xml and go to line activity android:configChanges at its end u'll find android:windowsoftInputMode="set it to adjustPan". This may solve your problem.

Comment: That one also tried currently the manifest has android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
This also didnt solved the issue

Comment: Is it by default adjustPan? Or you did change it?

Comment: Default has adjustPan

Comment: Put it adjustResize and rebuild your project